# R error: namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

Tags: r, ggplot2

I needed to reinstall R after experiencing the blank non-functional Rstudio. After that I got into big troubles with Rstudio, which now would start but is reacting in a weird way. I installed many times `ggplot2` and other packages, after which I am getting a message like:

`package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked. The downloaded  binary packages are in C:\Users\absolution\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIJr2z3\downloaded_packages`

But when I upload them I am getting an error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i, 1],     envir = env):cannot open file 'C:/Users/absolution/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or Directory
```

During this process I also observed twice a pop-up window asking if I would like to create a personal library, I clicked once no and the second time yes. So I dont know whats going on.

Here is what I got in the `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
 [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4    gtable_0.2.0   grid_3.4.4
```

I will highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Try this `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` to install all dependencies for `ggplot2`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. This time the Installation lasted longer. But the same error message appeared again. Is it usual that the downloaded packages are placed in the folder '~\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIJr2z3\downloaded_packages ', which I actually cant find ? Maybe it has no relevance. Do you have any other idea ? Also, it is not only about 'ggplot2' but also packages like 'readr', 'data.table', ...

Comment: Try install `Rcpp` then: install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Comment: If I understand you good, should I try first 'install Rcpp' in Rstudio ? I tried it anyway after which I got the error message:Error: unexpected symbol in "install Rcpp".

Comment: You just need to run install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "cran.us.r-project.org") . After that try to install ggplot again

Comment: Now I got this: 
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/absolution/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  scheme not supported in URL 'cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rcpp’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:
  scheme not supported in URL 'cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/PACKAGES'
>

Comment: Maybe you cannot access the US mirror. Delete `repos = "cran.us.r-project.org"` and try again

Comment: I followed your advice.The Installation of 'Rcpp' ended apparently well, just like that of 'ggplot2', but when I upload the package I get kind of same error: "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL ‘colorspace’ nicht gefunden: vielleicht für diese Architektur nicht installiert?". At this point should one uninstall R and/or Rstudio and then reinstall them ?

Comment: R is complaining about other package: `colorspace`. You need to update `colorspace`. It also a good idea to update all your library after that. Run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks.  I did it too. The problem is persisting. I dont know what to do.

Comment: The other fix I would suggest is: uninstall RStudio & R. Then delete library & R folders. Install everything from scratch. Then try `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: Many thanks. The new installation of both R & RStudio fixed all the problems.

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out in the end.